# What is the meaning of "slim pickings" there?

Tags: word-meaning

This is part of the script of an episode of *Two and a half men*.

> **(C)** Wake up.
>
> **(B)** What?
>
> **(C)** Mia wants sperm.
>
> **(B)** Well, don't look at me.
>
> **(C)** No, no, she wants my sperm. She wants me to make a deposit so she can
>   have a baby.
>
> **(B)** You're kidding.
>
> **(C)** Apparently, that's another of its uses.
>
> **(B)** What the hell is that?
>
> **(C)** I'm not sure. Near as I can tell, she's chasing a rabbit.
>
> **(B)** So why did Mia come to you?
>
> **(C)** Well, it turns out her biological clock is ticking. Most of the guys
>   she meets are ballet dancers, so, slim pickings there.

It is obvious that the reference is telling that people are gay there but what is the meaning of this reference "slim pickings"?

Full script [here](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=two-and-a-half-men&episode=s03e23)

Comment: Can you reformat the script to make it clearer who is speaking.  You can use one paragraph for each speaker, and perhaps put the speakers' name in bold at the start of each paragraph.

Comment: one line per character, alternate. First Charlie and then his brother. [See here](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=two-and-a-half-men&episode=s03e23)

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  Surely it should be "Wake up/What?/Mia wants sperm/" With a line break between "What" and "Mia". And then the line starting "No No" should continue up to "...have a baby".  The script website you quote uses subtitle scripts, which would be colour coded for broadcast, but aren't split clearly into speakers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without having actually seen the episode, I can only guess. However, in this context 'slim pickings' is probably understood to mean '*not many options*'.

Mia needs someone's sperm in order to have a baby, however many of the men she meets are ballet dancers. The joke here (I think, correct me if I am wrong) is that most ballet dancers are gay and thus, do not want to sleep with a woman. Therefore, Mia does not have many options to get a sperm donor so she can have a child.

Another example of this phrase can be:
"It was *slim pickings* on the last day of the sale."

Meaning, on the last day of the sale, there were not many options to choose from.

Comment: I was suspecting that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Slim picking in this (and most) context(s) is just an idiom to mean there aren't a lot of good choices available.

In this particular case, I believe it's trying to point out that most of the men she hangs around with are probably gay (stereotyping male ballet dancers) and therefore are not suitable people to get her pregnant.

Comment: I was suspecting that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> slim
>   slender, as in girth or form; slight in build or structure.
>   poor or inferior:
>   a slim chance; a slim excuse.
>   **small or inconsiderable; meager; scanty:**
>   a slim income.

> picking
>   **something that is or may be picked or picked up.**
>   the amount picked.
>   pickings,
>   scraps or gleanings:
>   the pickings of a feast.
>   profits or gains; spoils.

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/slim

"slim pickings" means that the options (things that may be picked) are scanty, i.e. there aren't many of them.